# Running a Swift file in the Swift REPL

Tags: swift, interpreter

In Python or Haskell I can run a file inside the REPL (e.g., in Python `execfile('foo.py')`). How can I do the same inside the Swift REPL. I'm not using Xcode.  I know if you put `#!/usr/bin/swift` at the top of a file, then you can run it from the shell, but I'd like to run from the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *run* a swift file from Swift REPL, but you can import a custom framework when running the REPL:

```
swift -F /path/to/ProjectName.framework
```

Then, import the framework:

```
> import ProjectName
```